# Variadic template. Size of the template arguement list in variadic template data structure

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a `tuple` style variadic template data type. I want to get `tuple_size` type function that gets the number of template parameters. However, I'm having trouble getting the following to work.

```cpp
template<typename... T>
struct A
{
};

template<typename T, typename ...S>
struct A<T, S...>
{
  T t;
  A<S...> s;
};


template<typename T>
size_t size_A()
{
  return 1;
}

template<typename T, typename... S>
size_t size_A()
{
  return 1 + size_A<S...>();
}


int main() {
  A<int,double,uint> a {2,3.5,10};
  constexpr size_t n = size_A<decltype(a)>();
  std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following error:

```cpp
error: call of overloaded ‘size_A<A<int, double, unsigned int> >()’ is ambiguous
   constexpr size_t n = size_A<decltype(a)>();

note: candidate: ‘size_t size_A() [with T = A<int, double, unsigned int>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
 size_t size_A()
        ^~~~~~

note: candidate: ‘size_t size_A() [with T = A<int, double, unsigned int>; S = {}; size_t = long unsigned int]’
 size_t size_A()
        ^~~~~~
```

How do I make it distinguish between having parameter packs and not having them?

The following does work but I want to just use the type and not have to find an instance of the type. The actual problem will have the type and maybe no instance of the type.

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr size_t size(const A<T>& t)
{
  return 1;
}

template<typename T, typename... S>
constexpr size_t size(const A<T,S...>& t)
{
  return 1 + size(t.s);
}
```

This differs from the varidic template functions where the instance of the type is given.

How do I make `size_A` work like `tuple_size` so that I can get the number of template parameters just by the type?

Comment: Just use `sizeof...(S)` to get the number of arguments in the pack `S`

Comment: Thank you. But, 
```template<typename... S>
constexpr size_t size_A()
{
  return sizeof...(S);
}```
This didn't work. It just returns 1 when it should be 3.

Comment: [possible Demo](https://ideone.com/eAYY69).

Comment: @Mochan must be an error somewhere else in the code, I'm confident `sizeof...(S)` returns the number of variadic argument in `S`.

Comment: That you @Jarod42. That works great. I didn't think of using  a `struct`. I was fixated on finding a way to `enable_if` with parameter packs.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot The following function with an instance works but without an instance doesn't work. I don't know why.
```
template<typename... S>
constexpr size_t size(const A<S...>& t)
{
  return sizeof...(S);
}
```

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot https://ideone.com/DkmBJP Here is the code doing this. I don't know what my error is.

Comment: @Mochan I copy pasted your code in compiler explorer. It still works: https://godbolt.org/z/cQTUXH

Comment: @Mochan I don't know what you expect your code do. Everything is correct. You are sending *only one* type to your `size_A` function. That type is `decltype(a)`. Try sending `int,double,uint` it will return `3`.

Comment: @Mochan you also implemented a working version above that returns `sizeof...(S)` correctly with the template arguments of `A` with your `size(a)` function. I really don't know what else do you need.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot  I wanted the size without an instance of `A`. I will only have the type of `A`. @Jarod42 gave me the solution which I will use.

Comment: @Mochan your solution with `size` in your ideone demo was superior. Jarod42 solution is much more slow to compile.

Comment: @Mochan this code avoid recusivity, is simpler and faster to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/cOxA7D

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thank you. Works great!